If every non-zero left module over a ring contains a simple submodule, does that necessarily mean the ring is a left Artin ring?
If $R$ is a left Artin ring, then any non-zero left module $M$ must contain a simple submodule. Since $M$ is not zero, we can take a non-zero element $m \in M$ and thus we obtain the finitely generated module $Rm$. Since $R$ is a left Artin ring, the finitely generated module $Rm$ must have finite length, and consequently, $Rm$ contains a simple submodule $S$, as does $M$.
As shown in the following diagram,
$$S \subseteq Rm \subseteq M \ .$$
So, is the converse true? In other words, if every non-zero left module over a ring contains a simple submodule, does that necessarily mean the ring is a left Artin ring?

No.  Such a ring is called a left semi-Artinian ring, and there are non-left Artinian examples.
For example, let $V$ be a countably infinite dimensional $F$ vector space, and consider $T=End_F(V)$. It turns out that the left and right socles of this ring coincide. Call that ideal $S$.
Now generate a subring $R$ of $T$ using $S$ and the diagonal copy of $F$.  This ring $R$ has a socle series up through $S$, and then $T/S\cong F$, so the socle series reaches all the way up to $R$.  This is true on both sides, so it is both left and right semi-Artinian.
This relies on an equivalence:

Every nonzero left $R$ module contains a simple submodule ("$R$ left semi-Artinian")
Every nonzero quotient of $_RR$ has a simple submodule

This is more or less obvious since every nonzero cyclic submodule is of the form $R/L$ for some left ideal $L$.

P.S. You can also produce a commutative counterexample with more or less the same trick inside $T=\prod_{\mathbb N}F_2$ and its socle $S=\oplus_\mathbb N F_2 $, to get $R=T/S$. The reasoning about the socle series remains true, and it again is (obviously) a nonartinian ring.

Here is the DaRT query

You are truly erudite! Thank you sincerely for your response!

The answer is no. Here's a commutative counterexample:
Take $$R=k[x_i:i \in \mathbb{N}]/\langle x_i^2:i \in \mathbb{N} \rangle$$ where $k$ is a field and let $M$ be a nonzero $R$-module. Let $m \in M$ be nonzero, so that $Rm \cong R/I$, where $I=annh(m)$. If $x_i \in I~\forall i$, then $I$ is maximal and $Rm$ is the desired simple submodule. Otherwise, $x_i \not\in I$ for some $i$. Then $$J=I \oplus kx_i$$ is an ideal and $I$ has $k$-codimension $1$ in $J$. So $J/I$ is a simple submodule of $R/I$, and the corresponding submodule of $Rm$ is a simple submodule of $M$.
